# Tratamento de data em formulario com php

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como ou se é possível colocar no formulário um campo data onde o usuário vai inserir no formato "22 de Fevereiro de 2019", ou alguma maneira de converter para isso pra salvar no banco de dados, obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa converter o mês para inglês ou numero de qualquer jeito, então já converte tudo de uma vez pro formato padrão

Comment: Tudo é possível, mas nem tudo é simples ou fácil. E se o usuário entrar com o mês "fevereiro", tudo minúsculo? E se errar a digitação, tipo "fefereiro"? Não é mais fácil criar um campo `<input type="date">` e o usuário selecionar o dia? Muito mais simples, fácil para ambos os envolvidos e, principalmente, já possui a formatação desejada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar criar um  que contenha os campos dos meses e os valores retornados por eles são os números de cada mês. Por exemplo:

```html
<select name="mes">
  <option value="01">Janeiro</option>
  <option value="02">Fevereiro</option>
  <option value="03">Março</option>
  <option value="04">...</option>
</select>
```

E no php:

```
<?php
$dia = $_POST['dia'];
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$ano = $_POST['ano'];

$valor_formatado_para_mysql = "$ano/$mes/$dia";

?>
```

Após isso, é só fazer o INSERT normalmente.